# C# enque random int

Tags: c#, multithreading, random, int, queue

I have three threads which are supposed to add a random int to a queue, a fourth that dequeues an int, and a fifth that prints the numbers within it.  I'm using threads because they will eventually be needed for the scope of this program and to enqueue/dequeue far more numbers, but having issues with generating a random int.  I'm using a class RandomGenerator to create the number, and creating an instance of this class then invoking its GetRandom method to set an int field to a random number.  I'm then passing this field into the first three threads which invoke the method to enqueue.  The int that prints is not random and I realize this is because I'm simply calling the method at the beginning of the program and passing the same exact number to all three threads.  I'm relatively new to C# and realize I may be making a basic mistake.  I also realize the fourth thread sometimes accesses the queue when it's empty but isn't as important at the moment.  I have tried a number of different things with this and could also have the number generator in the Program class.  Here is the code:

...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        RandomGenerator rg = new RandomGenerator();

        Queue<int> numberQueue = new Queue<int>();

        int randomNumber = rg.GetRandom(1, 10);

        Thread T1 = new Thread(delegate () { p.EnqueueNumber(numberQueue, randomNumber); });
        Thread T2 = new Thread(delegate () { p.EnqueueNumber(numberQueue, randomNumber); });
        Thread T3 = new Thread(delegate () { p.EnqueueNumber(numberQueue, randomNumber); });
        Thread T4 = new Thread(delegate () { p.DequeueNumber(numberQueue); });
        Thread T5 = new Thread(delegate () { p.PrintNumbers(numberQueue); });

        T1.Start();
        T2.Start();
        T3.Start();
        T4.Start();
        T5.Start();

        T1.Join();
        T2.Join();
        T3.Join();
        T4.Join();
        T5.Join();
    }

    public void EnqueueNumber(Queue<int> numberQueue, int randomNumber)
    {
        numberQueue.Enqueue(randomNumber);
    }

    public void DequeueNumber(Queue<int> numberQueue)
    {
        numberQueue.Dequeue();
    }

    public void PrintNumbers(Queue<int> numberQueue)
    {
        foreach (int i in numberQueue)
        {
            Console.Write(i);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class RandomGenerator
{
    private static Random _random = new Random();
    private static object syncLock = new object();

    public int GetRandom(int min, int max)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            return _random.Next(min, max);
        }
    }
}
```

...

Comment: Be careful with thread-safety. The `Queue` class is not thread safe. Also be aware that the pattern you are trying to implement is known as "producer-consumer" pattern, and that the .NET Platform includes specialized tools for implementing this pattern easily and robustly. You can take a look for example to the [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) class, which is not the best available, but it's the easiest to learn.

Comment: I would consider looking in to `[ThreadStatic] private static Random _random = new Random();` as this would eliminate the need to `lock` when getting random numbers.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, but at the cost of creating one `Random` instance per thread. Perhaps not a big deal, but important to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the return *value* of the `GetRandom()` method of your single `RandomGenerator` instance to each of the threads.

You need to pass a *reference* to the `RandomGenerator` to each of the threads instead, so `GetRandom()` can be called each time.

```
Thread T1 = new Thread(delegate () { p.EnqueueNumber(numberQueue, rg); });
```

If you create a `RandomGenerator` per thread you can also stop using locks which are overkill for this use case.

Finally if you insist on concurrent multi-write to, single-read from the same queue, you should also look at [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1) rather than Queue as it is thread-safe.

Comment: Be careful with the one random number generator per thread. If they're all initialized within the same millisecond, they're likely to each generate the same sequence of random numbers. The default constructor gets the seed from the system time, which is reported in milliseconds. Also, rather than `ConcurrentQueue`, I would suggest [BlockingCollection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.8). It has a somewhat more friendly interface. By default, it's backed by a `ConcurrentQueue`, so the behavior would be the same.